# msfconsole -r file.rc output format

Tags: metasploit

I need to check a host automatically with the help of msfconsole

The relevant checks are in `file.rc`, it's possible to automate that routine via docker image with command `RUN msfconsole -r file.rc`

After that all output processed as in the comment below:

`msfconsole -r /home/user/tests/test.rc 2>/home/user/data/test.rc_errors.txt 1>/home/user/data/test.rc_results.txt`

Problem: output of the above command provided "as is", when I need for example **.json**

Question: Is the way of defining the output format with the use of resoure files exist? Maybe exists some workaround I don't know about.. ? Or parsing this ugly output to get some important data is the only way out?